# Hyperref problem when using pdflscape

Tags: xetex, hyperref, landscape, pdflscape

As shown in the .gif animation below, a click on the link below the table will move the visual focus to the position just above the linked cell in the table.

[image: TestHyperlink_portrait.gif]

However, after the table is changed to landscape with the pdflscape package, a click on the link below the table only move the visual focus to the position above the entire table.

[image: TestHyperlink_landscape.gif]

Could you help to suggest how to achieve the same effect when the table is in landscape ?

The .tex files for the two situation are given below, which are opened using TexWorks from TexLive 2019 on Windows and compiled using XeLaTeX.

TestHyperlink_portrait.tex:

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmainfont[]{Times New Roman}
  \setmathfont[]{XITS Math}
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=cyan,
  filecolor=Maroon,
  citecolor=Blue,
  urlcolor=Blue,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\usepackage[top=3.18cm, bottom=3.18cm, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{title}{%
\section{TITLE}\label{title}}

AUTHOR

Affiliation

\large

\hypertarget{toc}{%
\section{Table of content}\label{toc}}

\normalsize

\newpage

\newgeometry{top=3.18cm, bottom=3.18cm, left=0.5cm, right=0.5cm}
\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}

\hypertarget{sec0}{%
\section{Results for section0.}\label{sec0}}

\hyperlink{toc}{Back to Table of content}

\hypertarget{tbl:tbl0_Numbers}{}
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lc@{}}
\caption{\label{tbl:tbl0_Numbers}Numbers for tbl0.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Description & Number\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Description & Number\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\(\mathbf{Parent 1}\) \protect\hypertarget{tblA1}{}{} &\tabularnewline
\hyperlink{figA1}{Child 1a} & -6666.666666\tabularnewline
\(\mathbf{Parent 2}\) \protect\hypertarget{tblB1}{}{} &\tabularnewline
\hyperlink{figB1}{Child 2a} & -7777.777777\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\normalsize

\restoregeometry

\hypertarget{figA1}{%
\subsection{Child 1a}\label{figA1}}

\hyperlink{tblA1}{Number  =         -6666.666666 }

\newpage

\hypertarget{figB1}{%
\subsection{Child 2a}\label{figB1}}

\hyperlink{tblB1}{Number  =         -7777.777777 }

\newpage

\end{document}
```

and

TestHyperlink_landscape.tex:

```
\documentclass[
  10pt,
  AutoFakeBold,AutoFakeSlant]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
  \setmainfont[]{Times New Roman}
  \setmathfont[]{XITS Math}
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=cyan,
  filecolor=Maroon,
  citecolor=Blue,
  urlcolor=Blue,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\usepackage[top=3.18cm, bottom=3.18cm, left=2.54cm, right=2.54cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{title}{%
\section{TITLE}\label{title}}

AUTHOR

Affiliation

\large

\hypertarget{toc}{%
\section{Table of content}\label{toc}}

\normalsize

\newpage

\newgeometry{top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm, left=1.2cm, right=1.6cm}
\fancyhfoffset[E,O]{0pt}

\begin{landscape}

\hypertarget{sec0}{%
\section{Results for section0.}\label{sec0}}

\hyperlink{toc}{Back to Table of content}

\hypertarget{tbl:tbl0_Numbers}{}
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}lc@{}}
\caption{\label{tbl:tbl0_Numbers}Numbers for tbl0.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Description & Number\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Description & Number\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\(\mathbf{Parent 1}\) \protect\hypertarget{tblA1}{}{} &\tabularnewline
\hyperlink{figA1}{Child 1a} & -6666.666666\tabularnewline
\(\mathbf{Parent 2}\) \protect\hypertarget{tblB1}{}{} &\tabularnewline
\hyperlink{figB1}{Child 2a} & -7777.777777\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\normalsize

\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry

\hypertarget{figA1}{%
\subsection{Child 1a}\label{figA1}}

\hyperlink{tblA1}{Number  =         -6666.666666 }

\newpage

\hypertarget{figB1}{%
\subsection{Child 2a}\label{figB1}}

\hyperlink{tblB1}{Number  =         -7777.777777 }

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are compiling with xelatex? Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The .tex files for the two situation are given below, which are opened using TexWorks from TexLive 2019 on Windows and compiled using XeLaTeX. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: In sumatra it works, but not with the internal pdf viewer of texworks. I guess it doesn't handle the /Rotate attribute correctly. Side remark: `\(\mathbf{Parent 1}\)` looks quite odd. Why don't you write `\textbf{Parent 1}`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your efforts ! <s>What do you mean by "it works" ?</s> :D The gif animations to demonstrate inconsistent hyperref behaviors in portrait and landscape were in fact recorded using SumatraPDF. The inconsistency was also tested on Adobe Reader. Indeed, here I used `\(\mathbf{Parent 1}\)` because sometimes that could be an actual equation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "I guess it doesn't handle the /Rotate attribute correctly." Thank you for your diagnosis ! Would it be possible for hyperref to handle /Rotate attribute correctly ?

Comment: The problem is not hyperref but (imho) the internal pdf viewer of texworks.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just double-checked with both SumatraPDF and Adobe Reader on Windows, and still got the inconsistent behavior between portrait and landscape modes. It should be noted that other unexpected behavior was observed with Chrome and Edge as PDF viewer, which supports your diagnosis. To sum up, for a long table shown in landscape using pdflscape (via /Rotate attribute), one cannot make accurate jumps to anchors defined in the cells of that table. :(

Comment: I tried with Acrobat Reader and it works as expected, jumping to the table cell when the corresponding link is clicked.. But you are right, with other PDF viewers (Chromium and Evince) the link target is not reached properly.

Comment: @AlexG Now I am lost !.... Thanks for your efforts but just to make sure, did you try `TestHyperlink_landscape.pdf` rather than `TestHyperlink_portrait.pdf` ? Would you be kind enough to make a gif animation, so that I know for sure the problem is not in .pdf file but in the viewer ?

Comment: Yes, I tested the landscape version.

Comment: @AlexG The link target is a bit unclear in the code, the anchor is behind the "Parent" text and not (as I would have expected) *before* the Parent.